# java sqlite PreparedStatement не возвращает результат

Tags: java, sqlite, preparedstatement

Не происходит вход в тело цикла while при использовании первого запроса (rs: колонок 2, строк 0).
Оба запроса рабочие, проверены в SQLiteStudio. Исключение (Exception) не происходит. 
Как исправить код, для использования первого запроса?

Первый запрос не возвращает ни одной строки:

```
String sql = "select sum(c_bytes) as c_bytes, DATE(c_time) as c_time from log group by DATE(c_time) order by c_time;";
```

Второй запрос возвращает строки:

```
 String sql = "select sum(c_bytes) as c_bytes, c_time as c_time from log group by c_time order by c_time;";
```

Код:

```
final String dbPath = "jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite";


        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath)) {
        if (conn != null) {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String c_time = rs.getString("c_time");
                int c_bytes = rs.getInt("c_bytes");
                //...
            }
            stmt.close();
        }



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Как только меняю `GROUP BY c_time` на `GROUP BY DATE(c_time)` возвращается результат с количеством строк = 0

Comment: А что возвращается ? null ?

Comment: не null.
Тип - JDBC4ResultSet в обоих запросах

Comment: Не понял. В строчке `rs.getString("c_time");` что будет возвращено ?

Comment: В первом случае ничего, т.к. нет строк в результате запроса. Во втором случае String, например: "1498311387000".

Comment: ну так нет строк, потому что запрос ничего не возвращает. что говорит db viewer ?

Comment: В SQLiteStudio всё нормально строки есть в обоих запросах.